# Windows Server 2012 actively refused connection via tcp/ip

Tags: windows-server-2012, tcp

Need help on this!

I'm trying to connect and send a message from my client pc to our host server (Windows Server 2012) via TCP/IP. I configured the DTC connections and also opened the firewall but I still get this error.
[image]

Any suggestions on what to configure in order to fix this?

UPDATE: Here is the "View Detail" section:
[image]

Comment: Any way you could post the "View Detail..." section?

Comment: Are you using credentials?

Comment: Check the update. I'm just testing this using Unit Test. But the main thing is that from Client to Host, connection is refused. But from Host to Client, connection is established. Which means that Host can send TCP/IP message to the Client machine

Comment: @lrb: What do you mean by credentials?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind credentials, this is a network issue during handshake prior to credentials. Can you ping from client to host?

Comment: @lrb: I can ping from client to host, and also tried the tracert as well. On both instances, they are successful.

Comment: You probably should provide more information. What are you attempting to connect to and what port will it be listening on?

Comment: @lrb: By default, it should listen to port 2020. But (1) I have no idea how to set it, or (2) shouldn't it be like a fixed port already?

Comment: Is this a server you created? If so then yes you can specify a specific port and you should so the client has a good idea how to connect.

Comment: How do you know the available ports in Windows Server 2012 and how do you set them? Because most of what I found is related to SQL Server but not in Windows Server 2012

Comment: Ok...take a step back if this is not "your" server we are referring to the please specify what Application you attempt to connect to when the error occurs the IP/PORT.

Comment: I'm connecting to my application which I deployed there but I didn't setup the server. My application accepts messages using TCP/IP.